# Should I always split my files into declarations (.h) and definitions (.cpp)

Tags: c++, split

To make some code easier to read I am splitting it across several files. One of those files just contains 2 initialisation methods. Is it worth creating a .h with the the declaration for those methods in, and including that, or should I just include the .cpp straight off, for just 2 methods, is it worth conforming to the standard?

Comment: **Never include .cpp files. Never. Ever.**

Comment: @H2CO3 Fair enough. Why not, I've seen it done in some examples? (Not saying it's right, just looking for an explanation as to why it isn't).

Comment: `ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64`

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule to splitting you file between `.h` and `.cpp`. I normally work with templates and make header only libraries so I have everything in a `.h` file.

Comment: @H2CO3 Can that not be solved with the old #ifndef #define #endif thing

Comment: @handuel (disregard) No, you can't.

Comment: I think the reason it's done in examples is to limit the amount of code to be displayed on a webpage (for readability).  But seriously, NEVER include .cpp files.  One reason I can think of is because it makes dependencies a nightmare, and may provide some classes access to functions they don't need access to.

Comment: @handuel You cannot solve link-time errors with preprocessor directives, because translation units are processed independently.

Comment: "is it worth conforming to the standard?" Not conforming to the Standard is usually Undefined Behavior (=anything can happen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never include cpp file, no matter how few definitions are in them: each definition included in several other cpp files would produce duplicate symbols, causing linking errors.

If you build a class that is used in multiple translation units (that's a fancy name for a cpp files) you should build a header for it. Templates go without a cpp file - only a header is necessary.

Although a common practice is to make one cpp/header pair for each class, it is OK to include multiple related classes in a single translation unit, and put all the declarations in a single header.

Comment: The compiler won't stop you from adding multiple related classes in a header, but be careful!  I had a project grow really large on me and eventually found it difficulty to location classes relating to a math library.  Even though they were all related, I would have spent less time searching for things had I actually separated them and kept the 1:1 header/translation unit paradigm.

Comment: @DJPeterson I agree, sticking multiple classes in a header should be an exception, not a rule. About the only time when I would consider it is when the classes for a "cluster" of tightly coupled items, for example, a class and its `friend` comparator. This situation should come up less frequently in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Like said before, you don't include .cpp files. If your code is needed around the project then headers are a must. However, you can always use extern too. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/21368/

Answer (score 1):

A `.cpp` file you include *is* a misnamed `.h` file.

`.cpp` and `.h` are extensions that mean something to programmers (and the occasional tool in the tool chain).  If you start `#include`ing `.cpp` files, you'll confuse other programmers (including yourself in a few months/years), even if you convince your tool chain how to deal with it.

Creating a header-file only set of tools or functions is sometimes acceptable.  Calling that file `.cpp` is not.